# Actual impact of ad blockers on Tor Browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, panopticlick

You risk making Tor browser signature unique anytime you add browser extensions. Are there any quantifiable differences between Tor browser with and without certain extensions?  How should one evaluate extensions?

There are no differences displayed by [panopticlick.eff.org](https://panopticlick.eff.org) if you have Privacy Badger and/or uBlock installed, or not installed, but that's only a coarse measure. Any thoughts on what else one should evaluate beyond what panopticlick.eff.org reports?

As an aside, I'd expect the Tor browser bundle does not benefit from Privacy Badger since the Tor browser blocks much cross-site scripting anyways.  Can anyone confirm that?

Answer (score 1):

Tor website clearly stated they have no responsibility about addons. Some addons make you more trackable while others may have no impact.
The reason is that addons can call out of the browser commands and send information with direct connection which voids your anonymity.
It is better to use tails with its browser + addons.
It is more trustable.

Comment: I was unclear perhaps, the question is : How should one evaluate extensions?  I would not consider "Wait on the Tor project to evaluate it" to be a good answer since they have limited time and funding/political reasons for not supporting ad blockers.